# Javascript Functions for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

As a newbie to Node.js development, I have done basic web development until this point, I have come across a problem in trying to learn more advanced javascript.

Are there resources to find out (in detail) what kind of parameters Node.js functions can take and whether they return values or not? I apologize if this sounds like a stupid question but I have looked through [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) and similar sites but they only show you based on javascript for manipulating css and html elements, not the more advanced stuff.

**How do developers know what parameters of a function to pass for advanced Node.js applications? I'm not looking for full solutions here, just some links to helpful sites other than the Node.js documentation.**

Comment: nodejs documentation *is* where you should be looking, or the github page for whatever library you're using.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [Node.js documentation??](http://nodejs.org/api/)

Comment: http://w3fools.com , a nodejs developer who learned his JS in w3schools sounds terrifying to me.

Comment: The github pages seem a little scarce on explanations (since they assume you know what your doing) but I dont really know what Im doing yet. Are there good resources to learn? Similar to [Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#a-full-blown-web-application-with-nodejs)?

Comment: And yea I have looked thru the documentation but its always a lot of googling and slow understanding involved with the documentation's language (im a newb)...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes I am sure it sounds scary because it doesn't really make sense to use W3 to learn Node jaavascript...

Comment: http://book.mixu.net/node/single.html is another book which is great for starters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in node.js functions can take whatever parameters their designers made them take. They return whatever their designers decided they should return.

Your custom node.js-based functions can take whatever parameters you decide they should take. They return whatever you decided they should return.

In JavaScript, a function can return any value, and can receive any value as a parameter. Notably:

- They can be numbers
- They can be booleans
- They can be strings
- They can be arrays
- They can be functions (very common for callbacks)
- They can be any other object

Even `null` and `undefined` are acceptable.

W3Schools is not a reference for node.js, and barely qualifies as a reference to JavaScript. As you noticed, their JavaScript tutorials are very focused on client-side browser usage.

You're better off reading [Mozilla's tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). Note that these tutorials do **not** cover node.js, but you can't really know node.js without knowing JavaScript, since node.js is based on JavaScript.

Let's take a look at a built-in node.js function:

[`http.createServer`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener)

> **http.createServer([requestListener])**
>
> Returns a new web server object.
>
> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the
>   'request' event.

As you can see, this function receives a single (optional) parameter, which is a function.
It returns an object which is the new web server. You can then use that object to call other node.js server functions.

Generally, the documentation is a good place to look for precise details, even though it's not beginner-friendly.

I know you asked for places other than the official documentation, but the official documentation is **THE** reference for this. Therefore, as soon as you learn the basics, you'll find the docs increasingly useful.

Comment: Thank you thats about as good as an answer gets for these kinds of questions. I will look into the Mozilla tutorial I didnt know about them before. I guess I will just have to dive in and learn from fumbling around for a while. :)

Comment: @arbabk Did you not know about Mozilla? Or is it just their tutorials you were unaware of?

Comment: LOL. No I knew about Mozilla... Just not their tutorials. Its resources like that I'm trying to find.

Comment: @arbabk I also heard good things about JavaScript: The Good Parts, but I have never actually had the opportunity to read it and the reviews on O'Reilly website seem to indicate that it's unsuitable for beginners.

Comment: @arbabk Take a look at https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#javascript and https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#nodejs